# how to create table in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a table in WordPress using dbDelta() function, below is the code

I have tried almost everything available on the internet and many of them is similar to the code that I have written, but still the table is not created in the database.

```
function mytable()
{
//    require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."books";
//    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    if ($wpdb->get_var('SHOW TABLES LIKE '.$table_name) != $table_name) {
        $sql = 'CREATE TABLE'.$table_name.'(
                book_id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                author_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                price float NOT NULL,
                publisher varchar (255) NOT NULL,
                year varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                edition varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                url text NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY  (book_id)
        )';
        require_once(ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);
        update_option('db_book_update', '1.0');
    }
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'mytable');
```

As I researched on the internet, I think my code is fine and it should work but still it is not working. Is there really any problem in my code or is there any other reason for not working of my code ??
Please help me out.

Comment: turn on your debug mode to show errors

Comment: You're missing a space between `CREATE TABLE` and `'.$table_name` which would explain why the query fails: `'CREATE TABLE'.$table_name.'(` should be `'CREATE TABLE '.$table_name.'(` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a space between **CREATE TABLE** and **'.$table_name** . It should be 'CREATE TABLE '.$table_name.'